# Why does `<span/ >` produce an empty span?

Tags: html, syntax, tags

In order to break long lines of text in the HTML source (because I prefer source code that approaches human readability) without introducing whitespace when
rendered, I have used source similar to

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>    
<p>
    Span<span/
    >in<span/    
    >the<span/
    >place<span/
    >where<span/
    >you<span/
    >live.
</p>
</body>    
</html>
```

Which renders something like

> Spanintheplacewhereyoulive.

However, I am not sure why this seems to work (using recent Chrome and Firefox, and a version of Konqueror). The [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-2) seems not to cover this situation, unless I have missed it. A [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5/3558200#3558200) suggests to me that the above example is not valid, insofar as the `<span/ >` tags are concerned.

Not sure it matters, but I want to emphasize that there is whitespace between the `/` and `>` in `<span/ >`. This is lexically distinct from `<span />` and `<span/>`, although I don't know if it's semantically different.

*Why* does `<span/ >` render, producing an empty span? Am I accessing some browser-specific behavior?

### Appendix

As far as I can tell, a correct way to break an empty span would be, for example, "Broken Up":

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>    
<h2>
                Continuous
</h2>
<p> /this/is/a/path/that/seems/not/to/end/it/goes/on/and/on/my/friend/someone/started/typing/it/not/knowing/what/it/was/and/they/will/continue/typing/a/long/time/because/this/is/a/path/that/seems/not/to/end/it/goes/on/and/on/my/friend/someone/started/typing/it/not/knowing/what/it/was/and/they/will/continue/typing/a/long/time/because
</p>
<h2>
                Broken Up
</h2>
<p>
<!-- 6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 -->
                /this/<wbr>is/a/<wbr>path/<wbr><span></span
                >that/<wbr>seems/<wbr><span></span
                >not/to/<wbr>end/<wbr><span></span
                >it/goes/<wbr>on/and/<wbr><span></span
                >on/my/<wbr>friend/<wbr><span></span
                >someone/<wbr>started/<wbr><span></span
                >typing/<wbr>it/<wbr>not/<wbr><span></span
                >knowing/<wbr>what/<wbr>it/was/<wbr><span></span
                >and/<wbr>they/<wbr>will/<wbr><span></span
                >continue/<wbr>typing/a/<wbr><span></span
                >long/<wbr>time/<wbr>because/<wbr><span></span
                >this/<wbr>is/a/<wbr>path/<wbr><span></span
                >that/<wbr>seems/<wbr><span></span
                >not/to/<wbr>end/<wbr><span></span
                >it/goes/<wbr>on/and/<wbr><span></span
                >on/my/<wbr>friend/<wbr><span></span
                >someone/<wbr>started/<wbr><span></span
                >typing/<wbr>it/<wbr>not/<wbr><span></span
                >knowing/<wbr>what/<wbr>it/was/<wbr><span></span
                >and/<wbr>they/<wbr>will/<wbr><span></span
                >continue/<wbr>typing/a/<wbr><span></span
                >long/<wbr>time/<wbr>because/
</p>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to render lines of text that are intended to be readable without any spaces.

Anyway, it seems the code doesn't actually produce empty `span` tags, but rather opens a tag that wraps the following text. It also seems to close only when a new tag opens.

Comment: @LeonardoBaptistaLopes RE "why... render... text... without any spaces:" For example, I may have narrow columns in my source code (maybe 48 characters) and long words (e.g., UUID's) where I need to insert `<wbr>` or other tags, which makes words even longer---so that they don't fit on one line of formatted source code.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `<span/ >` render, producing an empty span?

It doesn't.

The `/` is treated as an error and discarded. Whitespace is allowed between attributes and before the `>` of the tag.

> When the prescan a byte stream to determine its encoding algorithm says to get an attribute, it means doing this:
>
> If the byte at position is one of 0x09 (HT), 0x0A (LF), 0x0C (FF), 0x0D (CR), 0x20 (SP), or 0x2F (/) then advance position to the next byte and redo this step.
>
> If the byte at position is 0x3E (>), then abort the get an attribute algorithm. There isn't one.

— https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#concept-get-attributes-when-sniffing

The missing end tags are another error, and recovery rules inserts them when the end tag for the paragraph is reached.

> When the steps above say the user agent is to close a p element, it
> means that the user agent must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Generate implied end tags, except for p elements.
> 2. If the current node is not a p element, then this is a parse error.
> 3. Pop elements from the stack of open elements until a p element has been popped from the stack.

— https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#close-a-p-element

A normalised version of the HTML is:

```html
<p>
    Span<span>in<span>the<span>place<span>where<span>you<span>live.
</span></span></span></span></span></span></p>
```